# Connect to nginx server over RTMP with session id using FFmpeg

Tags: c++, nginx, ffmpeg

Is it possible with FFmpeg?
For example, if I use `NetConnection.connect()` method from Adobe ActionScript, I can send session id with following command:

```
connection.connect(_server, _sessionId);
```

I use this string to publish stream with FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -re -i D:\input.mp4 -c:v h264 -c:a aac -ar 8000 -ac 2 -f flv "rtmp://stream138.loadup.ru:443/broadcast/12950324_9893717_05515b7ad41d7e58005c14d3ff2c7947"
```

and I get error:

```
RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header:
rtmp://stream138.loadup.ru:443/broadcast/12950324_9893717_05515b7ad41d7e58005c14d3ff2c7947: Unknown error occured
```

Is it possible to do the same, when I used Adobe ActionScript, but with FFmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` uses [librtmp](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html). The supported options are listed on the linked man page.

You can add arbitrary AMF data to the connect with `conn`:

> **conn=type:data**
>
> Append arbitrary AMF data to the Connect message.
>
> The type must be B for Boolean, N for number, S for string, O for object, or Z for null. For Booleans the data must be either 0 or 1 for FALSE or TRUE, respectively. Likewise for Objects the data must be 0 or 1 to end or begin an object, respectively. Data items in subobjects may be named, by prefixing the type with 'N' and specifying the name before the value, e.g. NB:myFlag:1. This option may be used multiple times to construct arbitrary AMF sequences.
>
> E.g.
>
> conn=B:1 conn=S:authMe conn=O:1 conn=NN:code:1.23 conn=NS:flag:ok conn=O:0

Comment: great info, thanks! I solved my problem by adding '/' symbol at the end of MRL.